# Error installing laravel 5.6 app on remote hosting

Tags: laravel-5, hosting

I am trying to install my laravel 5.6 app on remote hosting(digital ocean, Ubuntu 16.04.3)

I set DocumentRoot in /etc/apache2/sites-available to /public of my app

I added line in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
ServerName localhost
```

and set all :

```
AllowOverride All
```

I made

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

and 
sudo service apache2 restart

and

```
# sudo apache2ctl configtest
Syntax OK
```

Running in browser I got message

> This page isn’t working NNN.NN.NN.NNN is currently unable to handle
>   this request. HTTP ERROR 500

As I see error code my web hosting ok, that is some specific intermal error?
But I want to see laravel error?

I run

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/box-booking/storage
```

log dir is empty:

```
and root@Box-Booking-Server:/var/www/html/box-booking/storage/logs# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 22 06:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jul 22 06:13 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   14 Jul 22 06:13 .gitignore
```

In my .env :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://NNN.NN.

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
```

In my /config/app.php I changed:

```
   'env' =>  'local',
 'debug' => true,
```

But I stiil can not see any error?

Is it some cache of config? How to see the errors?

Thanks!

Comment: Check apache error log file : /var/log/apache/error.log. Maybe this log will give you some clue